# Firebase get data conditionally

Tags: javascript, geolocation, firebase

I have a set of objects with coordinates stored in Firebase.

I have a function on the client side that runs trough every object in Firebase, because I only want to show the objects close to the clients coordinate.

My problem is that when the database gets larger, it will be heavy to download the whole thing for processing. I would like to do the processing server side, or somehow call only the objects closest to the client.

I hope its understandable! Can this be done?

Comment: Yup, most certainly possible. Have a look at the GeoFire library, which does exactly what you want by putting a geohash of the location into the .priority of each element and then filters on that. https://github.com/firebase/geofire/

Comment: It looks promising, i'm gonna try it out this weekend! thanks :)